# css background-image fadeout and fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I set up a site with a full-page filling background image (img/bg_start.jpg):
http://test.coffeeshop.abcde.biz/cascara/

If you move the mouse above the animal in the center of the page the current image (img/bg_start.jpg) should be faded-out and an other picture (img/bg_start2.jpg) should be faded in.

What I basically did is the following:

- Catching onMouseOver and -Out Event
- Executing in the case of onMouseOver:

```
$('#mask2').css({height: $(window).height(),width: $(window).width()}).fadeIn(800, function(){
    $('#mask1').fadeOut(800);
});
```

And in the case of OnMouseOut I do basically the same just in an other order (mask2/mask1)

mask1 and mask2 are defined like the following:

```
<div id="mask1" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-1000; opacity: 1.0;">

<div id="mask2" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-1000; opacity: 1.0; display:none">
```

Unfortunately the effect is not smooth but it's flickering.. can anyone help me please?!

Comment: Which browsers do you want to support the site in?

Comment: Try `$('#mask1').stop().fadeOut(800);`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so how's this for you: **http://jsfiddle.net/txezfv7d/**

Premise: one image is *always* visible. The second image is simply faded in or out depending on certain conditions. This means that you can't have flickering as the background is always visible.

### HTML

```
<div class="fader">Hover to fade</div>
<div id="mask1" class="mask"></div>
<div id="mask2" class="mask"></div>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.fader {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
.mask {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
    min-width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}
#mask1 {
    background-image: url("http://test.coffeeshop.abcde.biz/cascara/img/bg_start.jpg");
}
#mask2 {
    background-image: url("http://test.coffeeshop.abcde.biz/cascara/img/bg_start2.jpg");
    display: none; /* Initial state */
}
```

### JQuery

```
/* Set images to full screen */
$(".mask").width($(window).width());
$(".mask").height($(window).height());

$(".fader").mouseover(function () {
    $("#mask2").stop().fadeIn(800);
});
$(".fader").mouseout(function () {
    $("#mask2").stop().fadeOut(800);
});
```

Also note that I've set an initial height for your mask divs, which should allow for some slightly more graceful degradation if JS is not available on the client.

Comment: Hey gvee - thanks this works perfectly! One question why do I need the additional mask div-class?

Comment: @joe you don't need the extra class. But seeing as the two divs share a lot of common attributes I chose to group them together. Not only does it simplify your CSS but it also means you can target them both at the same time with the same JS.